# searching with choice text in django admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am extending user model with `AbstractUser` and added **CharField with choices** to it.
code looks like this

```
Location_choices = (
    ('IN', 'India'),
    ('USA', 'America'),
    ('O', 'Other Country')
)

class User(AbstractUser):
    location = models.CharField(choices=Location_choices, max_length=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

And registered in `admin.py` like below

```
class AdminUser(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('username', 'email', 'id', 'location')
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(User, AdminUser)
```

The problem is I am able to search with location choices **like (IN, USA, O)**
But I want to search with choice text **india or america**
How do I achieve It. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

How about Django's [list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)? I think it is very helpful widget to have in admin site.

Comment: Yes it is very helpful and done it using list filter. But let see anyone may answer how to do it without list filter